# SSIS: Is it possible to process excel file with dynamic column headers

Tags: ssis, excel

SSIS: Is it possible to process excel file with dynamic column headers.

For instance:
Excel file has 5 columns and we process that and save data in a table for all the 5 columns.
Now, the scenario is: file starts to have additional columns let's say 7 or sometimes the file has 3 columns. 
So, could anyone please help if it is possible in SSIS to work with dynamic columns in excel. If yes, how?

Comment: Are the column names always the same?

Comment: Yes, the first 5 column names are always same and for additional columns we don't know as they will come dynamically.

Comment: http://micktechblog.blogspot.co.nz/2011/06/ssis-excel-import-with-unknown-number.html?m=1

Comment: http://www.cozyroc.com/ssis/data-flow-task